# removing a redirected URL

Tags: url, redirect

While conducting a simple exercise using Node.js, I redirected the URL localhost:3000 on my Safari browser v 6.1 to an actual site. Believing that the redirect was only in effect while the node server was running, now I can't seem to remove it. Is there a way to resolve the URL back to 'server not found' status? The URL `http://127.0.0.1:3000` seems to behave properly by returning a 'server not found' status.

Mac OS X 10.8.5

Comment: I believe that you can solve this properly in [this StackExchange forum](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I really do. Completely out of topic...